# access denied ("java.io.FilePermission")

Tags: java, eclipse, file, permissions, ioexception

I'm working on a Java project with Eclipse Java and i'm getting permission errors. This is my code:

```
File file12 = new File("/Signature Manager/war/keys/file.p12");

file12.setWritable(true);
file12.setReadable(true);

if(file12.exists()){
    System.out.println("file exists");
}
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: What are the permissions on _file.p12_? Are you running Linux or Windows? You can't set file permissions on a file you don't own.

Comment: Does this java project or your current workplace is in C drive.If yes then create the file in any drive except C drive.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong your eclipse workplace or your current project is made in the C drive just move it to some another drive and then try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you file is readable and writable.
Or you can move that folder from C drive to some other drive

You can check `if(file12.canWrite()) file12.setWritable(boolean writable);`
and `if(file12.canRead()) file12.setReadable(boolean readable);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {

      File file = new File("/Signature Manager/war/keys/file.p12");

      if(file.exists()){
          System.out.println("Is Execute allow : " + file.canExecute());
      System.out.println("Is Write allow : " + file.canWrite());
      System.out.println("Is Read allow : " + file.canRead());
      }

      file.setExecutable(true);
      file.setReadable(true);
      file.setWritable(true);

      System.out.println("Is Execute allow : " + file.canExecute());
      System.out.println("Is Write allow : " + file.canWrite());
      System.out.println("Is Read allow : " + file.canRead());



    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```